# How to create a for loop in R for naming multiple CSV in a data list?

Tags: r

I am trying to name each dataframe within a list using forloop. It works for the first dataframe but then it seems to be rewriting for the others. so instead of getting a list of named CSV, I am getting the first and last (last is written as NA).

```
for (i in 1:length(data_list)){
  column_final<-data_list[[i]]
  
  excluded_df<-column_final %>% 
    select(-any_of(c("Plot.Project","Plot.ID")))
  name_project<-column_final$Plot.Project[i]
  name_plot<-column_final$Plot.ID[i]
  
  name4write<-paste0(name_project,"_",name_plot,"_browns.csv")
  write.csv(excluded_df,name4write, row.names = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious issue, but without a reproducible example we can only guess. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I am trying to name 18 dataframes, but when I run the code these are the results: DENA_HQ_TX_01_browns.csv (which is correct) and then NA_NA_browns.csv (this has the information of the last dataframe). It looks like its running through all the dataframes but not saving them.

Comment: I don't understand how you can have index `i` as an index into the list `data_list` but then index columns of `data_list[[i]]` with the very same `i` in `column_final$Plot.Project[i]` and `column_final$Plot.ID[i]`.`

Comment: Yes I understand the results. But without a reproducible example it is hard to say why that is happening. I agree with Rui that the use of `i` in `name_project` and `name_plot` looks odd. Since it's a loop, you can just set e.g. `i <- 2` and see what is happening. Are the correct `name_project` and `name_plot` being created?

Comment: yes, we changed that to 1 and it worked!!!!!!!! column_final$Plot.Project[1] and column_final$Plot.ID[1]

Answer (score 1):

Without data it's difficult to say but try

```
lapply(data_list, \(column_final) {
  excluded_df <- column_final %>% 
    select(-Plot.Project, -Plot.ID)))
  
  name_project <- column_final$Plot.Project[1L]
  name_plot <- column_final$Plot.ID[1L]
  
  name4write <- paste0(name_project, "_", name_plot, "_browns.csv")
  write.csv(excluded_df, name4write, row.names = FALSE)
})
```

Note that the first values of columns `Plot.Project` and `Plot.ID` are the ones used to put the file name together in the `paste0` instruction.